# Regex multiple line breaks

Tags: regex, vim

I want to substitute the value of HTML `<br>` tag with 2 newlines. i.e what i want to is

```
$string=~s/br>/\n\n/s;
```

but somehow it doesn't work. Whereas it works fine for a single new line.
i.e. if i do this:

```
$string=~s/br>/\n/s;
```

it works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please paste your file snippet and what you want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about vim's `substitute` command then you probably want to use `\r` in the replacement string instead of `\n`.  In this context vim treats `\n` as NULL, not newline.

Relevant snippet from `:help sub-replace-special`:

```
<CR>    split line in two at this point
        (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)          *s<CR>*
\r      idem                                       *s/\r*
\<CR>   insert a carriage-return (CTRL-M)
        (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)          *s/\<CR>*
\n      insert a <NL> (<NUL> in the file)
```